# Efficient way to convert an int to Hex string and then pad it with 0's in Golang?

Tags: string, performance, go, type-conversion, hex

I'm trying to convert 10 millions of int to Hex, then, padding it with 0's in order to get a 4 characters string which represents the Hex number.

So far, I tried the following:

```
var hexNumber string
for idx := O; idx < 10000000; idx++ {
    hexNumber = fmt.Sprintf("%04x", idx)

    // Do some stuff ....
}
```

But `fmt.Sprintf` is not very efficient. How can I achieve this in a efficient way?

**Solution:** It turns out that @peterSO `strconv.AppendInt` solution is way faster.

```
package bench

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

var stringHex [16]string
var runesHex [16]rune

func init() {
    stringHex = [16]string{"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}
    runesHex = [16]rune{'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'}
}

func intToHex1(intNumber int) string {
    hexNumber := []rune("0000")
    for i, j := int(0), uint(12); i < 4; i, j = i+1, j-4 {
        hexNumber[i] = runesHex[(intNumber>>j)&0x0f]
    }
    return string(hexNumber)
}

func intToHex2(intNumber int) string {
    hexNumber := "0000"
    for i, j := int(0), uint(12); i < 4; i, j = i+1, j-4 {
        hexNumber = hexNumber[:i] + stringHex[(intNumber>>j)&0x0f] + hexNumber[i+1:]
    }
    return hexNumber
}

func BenchmarkFmtSprintf(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        hexNumber := fmt.Sprintf("%04x", n)
        _ = hexNumber
    }
}

func BenchmarkStrconvFormatInt(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        retStr := strings.Repeat("0", 4) + strconv.FormatInt(int64(n), 16)
        hexNumber := retStr[(len(retStr) - 4):]
        _ = hexNumber
    }
}

func BenchmarkAppend(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    buf := []byte{'0', '0', '0', '0', 4 + 16: 0}
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        buf = strconv.AppendInt(buf[:4], int64(n), 16)
        hexNumber := string(buf[len(buf)-4:])
        _ = hexNumber
    }
}

func BenchmarkIntToHex1(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        hexNumber := intToHex1(n)
        _ = hexNumber
    }
}

func BenchmarkIntToHex2(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        hexNumber := intToHex2(n)
        _ = hexNumber
    }
}
```

So the benchmark:

```
BenchmarkFmtSprintf-2            3000000               364 ns/op              16 B/op          2 allocs/op
BenchmarkStrconvFormatInt-2      5000000               354 ns/op              15 B/op          3 allocs/op
BenchmarkAppend-2               20000000                75.6 ns/op             0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkIntToHex1-2            10000000               162 ns/op               8 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkIntToHex2-2             3000000               536 ns/op              16 B/op          4 allocs/op
```

Comment: You should clamp the value of `n` or `s` to `[0x0000, 0xFFFF]` for `s := fmt.Sprintf("%04x", n)`. Otherwise, you will get too many hex digits when `b.N > 0xFFFF`(65,535). For example, `n := 0x7FFFF; s := fmt.Sprintf("%04x", n)`, `s` is `7ffff`, five hex digits: https://play.golang.org/p/hX4R1aocIJ. See my revised answer, an even faster version of Append.

Comment: This is an old posting but meh: It turns out that using fmt.Sprintf, strconv.FormatUint and strconv.AppendInt aren't that fast. I've written a little package https://github.com/FMNSSun/hexit and depending on your exact use case (need string, need []byte, have preallocated buffer) the functions I wrote are generally much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strconv.AppendUint` appears to be faster than `fmt.Sprintf`. For example,

`hex_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkFmtSprintf(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        hexNumber := fmt.Sprintf("%04x", n&0xFFFF)
        _ = hexNumber
    }
}

func BenchmarkAppend(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        buf := []byte{'0', '0', '0', 3 + 4: 0}
        buf = strconv.AppendUint(buf[:3], uint64(n)&0xFFFF, 16)
        hexNumber := string(buf[len(buf)-4:])
        _ = hexNumber // Do some stuff ....
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test -bench=. hex_test.go
BenchmarkSprintf-4      10000000       116 ns/op      16 B/op     1 allocs/op
BenchmarkAppend-4       100000000       19.2 ns/op     0 B/op     0 allocs/op
```

Comment: Updated to an even faster version.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is the best way to do it, but I have [a gist](https://gist.github.com/jpgoldberg/a9b9212e5bcd43db1c4cb08395fbcbe1) and [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/tpmlYfq7NYF) illustrating the problem you are trying to solve and the approach I eventually took.

```golang
// hex formater with %x can lose a leading 0
// This can produce strings with an odd number of hex digits

package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var foo uint16 = 0x0ABC // decimal 2748

    with_pct := fmt.Sprintf("%x", foo)
    fmt.Printf("With string formatter: %q\n", with_pct)
    // Outputs: With string formatter: "abc"

    // I hope there is a cleaner way to get an integer into a []byte
    foo_bytes := make([]byte, 2)
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint16(foo_bytes, foo)

    with_bytes := hex.EncodeToString(foo_bytes)
    fmt.Printf("With hex encoding: %q\n", with_bytes)
    // Outputs: With hex encoding: "0abc"
}
```

I am not particularly happy with this approach. I have to manually set the length of the byte array based on the size of the int, as Go's `len()` function isn't like C's `size_of` operator.

This does work more nicely when trying to get a hex representation of an non-negative big.Int, as `.Bytes()` gives us the big-endian byte array.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use strconv, then just pad manually. This probably does less work.

```
strconv.FormatInt(idx,16)
```

Comment: Try that on decimal 2748. You will get `"abc"` when you almost certainly want `"0abc"`

Comment: That's why I said pad manually. See BenchmarkStrconvFormatInt example above in the revised answer.